# 'Mental illness' or 'Mental disorder' or 'Mental condition'?

Tags: meaning

I was recently diagnosed with ADHD, and when talking about it, and other mental conditions like depression, bi-polar, schizophrenia, I'm wondering what term to use.

Is there perhaps a distinction between mental conditions that are *disruptive* and mental conditions that *just are* (and require managing)?

Eg. Someone might argue 'I have depression and this requires curing' (much like cancer requires curing). Someone else might argue 'I have ADHD, and this is just a part of my personality'.

Can someone help shine some light on the distinction between these terms?

Comment: ADHD is classified as a neurodevelopmental disorder in [DSM-5](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/DSM-5#) and a hyperkinetic disorder in [ICD-10](http://apps.who.int/classifications/icd10/browse/2015/en#/F90-F98) It is regarded as a chronic behavioural disorder with onset usually occurring in childhood and adolescence. I guess you missed out on being diagnosed in childhood. Clinical depression can be a chronic condition too. Good info on adult ADHD at [ENAA](http://www.eunetworkadultadhd.com)

Answer (score 3):

This is somewhat based on personal opinion and what I have seen from other people, but I tend to make a distinction between "mental illness" and mental "disorders" or "conditions", loosely speaking.

With potentially *temporary* things that one isn't born with, such as anxiety or depression, I might be more inclined to use *mental illness*, or, if I wanted to avoid the unfortunately extreme connotations of the such, as *mental health issues*. In these cases, there's some sense that *ideally*, the various problems might go away.

Conversely, if I were to receive a diagnosis of high-functioning Asperger's, I might describe myself as *neurodivergent* or as having a mental *condition*, because of the stronger connotations of *disability* as something that is very prohibitive towards having a normal life.<sup>1</sup> While that also works in much more extreme cases, such as with Down's syndrome in [this report](https://web.archive.org/web/20150531094240/http://www.scmp.com/news/hong-kong/education-community/article/1813154/hong-kong-woman-90-fears-future-son-downs-amid-11), I'd be more inclined to say mentally *disabled* or *handicapped*, as the effect on life is much more severe.

Either way, it seems that there's usually some separation from how [developmental disorders](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Developmental_disorder) are treated (at least in more socially aware discussions) in comparison to other mental illnesses or disabilities, which makes sense, and which I think this language should *ideally* deal with.<sup>2</sup> This seems reasonable: the long-term approach one might have towards someone with autism or ADHD is different from that one might have towards someone with a spate of bad anxiety.

A point of comparison I usually bring up is this: we describe people with cancer or the flu as being *ill*, we describe people with eczema or various allergies as simply having certain health *conditions*, and we describe people with more limiting problems like very severe eye conditions or with severe injuries to their body as *disabled*. (There's also, to boot, similar ambiguity, in terms of "conditions" that may come up later in life, and with the distinction between "conditions" and disability, or between "illness" and disability.)

---

1. I should add that I'm doubtful of some of the uses of related concepts, as discussed e.g. [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neurodiversity#Controversies), but "neurodivergent" is loose enough that it doesn't bring in connotations that I think are inappropriate.
2. (It's possible the neurodivergence concept introduces additional problems: the examples in [this Urban Dictionary entry](https://web.archive.org/web/20141104194300/http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=neurodivergent) imply that to some, this language can be a means of sugar-coating severer afflictions or mental illness.)

Comment: +1 I totally concur. ADHD is about a deviation in the way the brain processes information. It literally is who you are. It makes functioning in society harder. And that is what all the fuss is about, otherwise it would have been just a trait.

Comment: @Bookeater: thanks! [Although reading example usage of "neurodivergence", I'm afraid that some people use such language in order to make such things "just a trait", unless I'm misinterpreting them. (Makes sense perhaps for high-functioning people who will be fine, but otherwise it strikes me as unproductive.) All the same, I personally still find the term useful as something less extreme than "disability" and that "illness" cannot cover. We also get a lot of ambiguity as to how to classify things, but probably not much more than we have with physical problems, imo.]